# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed. vs 2010 and sql server 2008 express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In VS 2010 I use these steps to connect to SQL Server database:

1. in server explorer window,Right Click on Data Connections
2. Click Add Connection
3. in choose data source window ,select SQL Server
4. click continue, button
5. "Add Connection" window will appear
6. in the server name text box type ".\sqlexpress"
7. in the select or enter database name type"Person"
8. Click Test Connection -- i see "test connection successed"
9. Finally Click OK Button

At step 9 I see this error: "Unable ti find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider It May not be Installed"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a self terminating node in the **machine.config** file. **Removing it** solved the issue.

**machine.config is found in**

```
\Windows\Microsoft.net\Framework\vXXXX\machine.config
```

You could have a multitude of config files based on how many versions of the framework are installed, including 32 and 64 bit variants.

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Odbc Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.Odbc" ... />
        <add name="OleDb Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.OleDb" ... />
        <add name="OracleClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data ... />
        <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data ... />
        <add name="IBM DB2 for i .NET Provider" invariant="IBM.Data ... />
        <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" ... />     
    </DbProviderFactories>

    <DbProviderFactories/>  //remove this one
</system.data>
```

Above file remove  `<DbProviderFactories/>` empty tag.

For additional reading [**Obtaining a DbProviderFactory (ADO.NET)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Are you using a sock puppet account?

Comment: @HansPassant Actually If I don't know something then I try to find it on the web and give it to the client what he is expecting(meantime I am also learning.That's why I joined here) .Is it wrong ? Tell me how to do it properly.B'cos I am quiet new to Stack Overflow.